# Display terms used by another term on archive page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've some custom taxonomies (doors qty) for vehicle (post type) and brands (another taxonomy).

When user click on Taxonomy: 2 or 4 doors, i need display **on post type archive page** all brands with 2 or 4 doors, for example: Honda, Toyota, Hyundai.

Unfortunately WordPress can't filter with this data to display the terms.

I try this:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'brand',
); ?>
<?php $terms = get_terms( $args ); ?>
<?php foreach ($terms as $term ) : ?>
    <?php /* Ok, here display a name of brand from vehicles with 4 doors */ ?>
    <?php echo $term->name; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This code display all brands, but i need display only brands with 4 doors.

Watching documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/ i see this:

```
'meta_query' => '',
'meta_key' => array(),
'meta_value'=> '',
```

Is there the correct way to filter brands with 4 doors?

Please consider that i use this only on archive page (archive.php) and i can use queried object to pass any data ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay

I resolve this, thinking `terms` wasn't correct way. The correct way is make a Custom Post Type called `Brands` and make it relational with another Custom Post Type or Term (in my case: `Door Qty`).

If you are interesting in Custom Post Types, please see this documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Excuse my english.